# Why can't I add weather widgets on Samsung Galaxy S10?

Tags: samsung, app-widgets, weather

I want to add a 2x2 dynamic weather widget to the home screen of my Samsung Galaxy S10 running Android 12.

When I select the widget, it opens the settings screen and asks me to select a location. When I attempt to make a selection, the widget window disappears.

I've had this widget on my phone for months and it worked fine before I deleted it. Weather widgets are the only widgets that won't install on my phone. Please help.

Comment: When the "widget window disappears" this could be because the app the widget belongs to crashes. You can try to clear app data of the app and check the reviews on Google Play Store if this is a common problem.